# How to show convexity in $\mathbb{R}^3$ without using principal minors?

Tags: convex-analysis, quadratic-forms

For example, suppose I have a function:

$$f(x_1,x_2,x_3) = x_1x_2 + x_1x_2 + x_1x_3$$

How can I show this is convex/concave or neither without using principal minors?

Is it just using the following?

$$f(y) - f(x) \leq Df(x)(y-x)$$

In that case, I would have some inequality to examine, but I'm unsure how to show if it is neither convex, nor concave (which is the answer I get using principal minors).

Comment: Since this is a quadratic function, the Hessian is constant. Do you know how to characterize that a twice continuously differentiable function is convex/concave/neither on its domain by analyzing its Hessian?

Comment: Yes, and I have done that, but for an exercise I am required to further verify the 'neitherness' of this property using the definition of convexity. I was unsure what that definition is/how to apply it

Comment: You just need 2 points w, z such that $(1/2)f(w)+(1/2)f(z)>f((1/2)w+(1/2)z)$, then another two points for $<$. If you take two random points you are likely to verify one or the other, which is a good start.

Comment: and just one instance is a proof that it is neither concave/convex everywhere? I thought that would just be for those specific points.

Comment: Why $x_1x_2 + x_1x_2$ instead of $2 x_1x_2$?